# GPU optimization pass in LLVM

Tags: opencl, llvm

Is adding an optimization pass for AMD OpenCL any different from writing an LLVM pass as in [Writing an LLVM Pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html). What additional knowledge should I have to accomplish this?. Do we need some extra libraries to optimize the OpenCL kernel?

Comment: I got the answer for this in [AMD forums](http://forums.amd.com/devforum/messageview.cfm?catid=390&threadid=154831&enterthread=y)

Comment: In such cases it's recommended at stackoverflow to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this in [AMD Forums](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1259960#1259960) (updated the link)